# Twilio Conversations to integrate SMS and Chat participants

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-conversations

I followed the guide exactly (https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart?code-sample=code-add-a-conversation-participant-sms&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=6.x)
but when I plug my Chat Token into the ChatApp.js from the Twilio CodeSandBox that I forked, I receive an authentication error and no participants are added.

I've repeated the process many times by deleting the Conversation-SIDs and starting over but same error every time. I'm confident that my CH, IS, Chat Tokens, etc are all correct.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try plugging your chat token into https://jwt.io/, to see if it looks valid? (i.e. expiration date, account SID, etc?)

Comment: I did and when I first copy/paste it says Invalid, but then when I click the "secret base64 encoded" checkbox, it changes the token and then says Valid. I've tried pasting both of the tokens in the ChatApp.js file and neither work.
I'm thinking thats my issue but I don't know how to fix it or format it properly. I copy/paste the token straight from cmd terminal just like they do in the tutorials.... however I will say mine looks much much longer (but theirs could just be scrolled off their screen)

Comment: May be best to open a support ticket with Twilio via the Twilio Console (upper right corner under the `?` icon) or help@twilio.com with a copy of your Chat access token, so they can see what the issue may be. Make sure the Account SID/Auth Token the Twilio CLI used to create the Auth token are correct too. See if you can execute other commands from the Twilio CLI to see if those commands work - https://www.twilio.com/docs/twilio-cli/examples

Comment: I appreciate your help Alan. I've checked and rechecked my acct_sid, auth_token, I almost have them memorized lol.  

I opened a support ticket a couple of days ago and its been forwarded to the "appropriate specialist" since its beta ???

I see you're a fellow Atlantian =)

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what I was doing wrong.
When I made my Chat Token, I had the wrong Profile active.
Now I know what Twilio profiles are lol